# Designing a Moore sequence detector using three always blocks

Tags: verilog, state-machines, sequence-detector

Trying to implementing a Moore state machine using three always blocks. The Moore state machine has two inputs (`ain[1:0]`) and one output (`yout`). The output `yout` begins as 0 and remains a constant value unless one of the following input sequences occurs:

- (i) The input sequence ain[1:0] = 01, 00 causes the output to become 0
- (ii) The input sequence ain[1:0] = 11, 00 causes the output to become 1
- (iii) The input sequence ain[1:0] = 10, 00 causes the output to toggle.

```verilog
    module moore_sequence_detector_3_blocks(
    input clk,
    input reset,
    input [1:0] ain,
    output reg yout
    );
    reg[2:0] state, nextstate;
    parameter S0=0, S1=1, S2=2, S3=3, S1_To_S0=4, S2_To_S0=5, S3_To_S0=6;
     
    always @(posedge clk or posedge reset) // always block to update state
        if(reset)
        begin
            state <= S0;
        end
        else
        begin
            state <= nextstate;
        end
     
    always @(state or ain) // always block to compute nextstate
    begin
        case (ain)
            2'b00:
                if(state == S1)
                    nextstate = S1_To_S0;
                else if(state == S2)
                    nextstate = S2_To_S0;
                else if(state == S3)
                    nextstate = S3_To_S0;
                else
                    nextstate = state;
            2'b01: nextstate = S1;
            2'b10: nextstate = S2;
            2'b11: nextstate = S3;
            default: nextstate = S0;
        endcase
    end
    
    always @(state) // always block to compute output
        begin
            case(state)
                S0: yout = 0;
                S1_To_S0: yout = 0;
                S2_To_S0: yout = ~yout;
                S3_To_S0: yout = 1;
                default:
                    yout = yout;
            endcase
        end endmodule
```

I cant seem to figure out what is wrong. The states should work as follows:

[image]

```
sout0  yout = 0
sout1  yout = 1

swait1  yout = 0
swait2  yout = 0
swaitInv0  yout = 0

swait3  yout = 1
swait4  yout = 1
swaitInv1  yout = 1

swaitInv0 -> sout1
```

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Answer (score 1):

You state machine coding is rather weird.

You normally start with looking which state you are in and then respond to the input to go to a new state. Also you should give your states better names.

```
case (state)
SEEN_00: 
    case (ain)
    2'b00 : next_state = SEEN_00;
    2'b01 : next_state = SEEN_01;
    2'b10 : next_state = ..
    2'b11 : next_state = ..
    endcase
SEEN_01 : 
    case (ain)
    2'b00 : next_state = ..
    2'b01 : next_state = ..
    2'b10 : next_state = ..
    2'b11 : next_state = ..
    endcase
SEEN_10 :
    ...
SEEN_11 :
    ...
endcase
```

Now here is a nice trick if you need to react to state **transitions**. You look at the current state and the next state:

```
if (state==SEEN_01 && next_state==SEEN_00) 
   yout <= ...
else
   if (state==SEEN_10 && next_state==SEEN_00)
```

This is an example where the coding using a `state` and `next_state` gives you a huge advantage against just writing `state <=  SEEN_..;`

With this the state machine code becomes regular and thus trivial.

### Now here is a nice GOTCHA:

Note that the output yout is registered and is not combinatorial depending on an input.

*Thus this is NOT a Mealy machine.*

At the same time the output is NOT dependent on the state as in state SEEN_00 the yout can be 0 or 1 depending on the *previous* state. Thus if you take the definition of a Moore machine literally "a Moore machine is a finite-state machine whose output values are determined only by its current state. "

*This is NOT a Moore machine either*.

Answer (score 0):

```
always @(state) // always block to compute output
    begin
        case(state)
            S0: yout = 0;
            S1_To_S0: yout = 0;
            **S2_To_S0: yout = ~yout;**
            S3_To_S0: yout = 1;
            default:
                **yout = yout;**
        endcase
    end endmodule
```

In the above code i am seeing latch formation usually which is not preferred in the synthesizable codes, and the FSM you have written is kind of new style which i haven't seen till now, from the state transition diagram you have provided i have written the FSM for the same in system verilog  , please go through it if needed:

```
module sequence_detector (
    input        clk,reset
   ,input [1:0]  ain
   ,output logic yout
);

logic nyout;
enum logic [3:0] {   START
                    ,SWAIT_1,SWAIT_2,SWAIT_3,SWAIT_4
                    ,SWAITINV_0,SWAITINV_1
                    ,SOUT_0,SOUT_1
                    ,XXX = 'x
                 } state,next;

always_ff @(posedge clk or posedge reset)
    if(reset) state <= #1 START;
    else      state <= #1 next;

always_comb begin 
        next = 'x;
   casez(state)
    START      :case(ain)
                    2'b01 : next = SWAIT_2   ;
                    2'b10 : next = SWAITINV_0;
                    2'b11 : next = SWAIT_1   ;
                endcase
    SWAIT_1   :case(ain)
                    2'b00 : next = SOUT_1    ;
                    2'b01 : next = SWAIT_2   ;
                    2'b10 : next = SWAITINV_0;
                endcase
    SWAIT_2   :case(ain)
                    2'b00 : next = SOUT_0    ;
                    2'b01 : next = SWAITINV_0;
                    2'b11 : next = SWAIT_1   ;
                endcase
    SWAIT_3   :case(ain)
                    2'b00 : next = SOUT_1    ;
                    2'b01 : next = SWAIT_4   ;
                    2'b10 : next = SWAITINV_1;
                endcase
    SWAIT_4   :case(ain)
                    2'b00 : next = SOUT_0    ;
                    2'b10 : next = SWAITINV_1;
                    2'b11 : next = SWAIT_3   ;
                endcase
    SWAITINV_0:case(ain)
                    2'b00 : next = SOUT_0 ;
                    2'b01 : next = SWAIT_2;
                    2'b11 : next = SWAIT_1;
                endcase
    SWAITINV_1:case(ain)
                    2'b01 : next = SWAIT_4;
                    2'b10 : next = SOUT_0 ;
                    2'b11 : next = SWAIT_3;
                endcase
    SOUT_0    :case(ain)
                    2'b01 : next = SWAIT_2   ;
                    2'b10 : next = SWAITINV_0;
                    2'b11 : next = SWAIT_1   ;
                endcase
    SOUT_1    :case(ain)
                    2'b00 : next = SWAITINV_1;
                    2'b01 : next = SWAIT_4   ;
                    2'b11 : next = SWAIT_3   ;
                endcase
   endcase
end

always_ff @(posedge clk or posedge reset)
    if(reset) yout <= #1 1'b0;
    else      yout <= #1 nyout;

always_comb begin
        nyout = 'x;
  case(state)
    SOUT_0,SWAITINV_0,
    SWAIT_1,SWAIT_2     : nyout = 1'b0;
    SOUT_1,SWAITINV_1,
    SWAIT_3,SWAIT_4     : nyout = 1'b1;
  endcase
end

endmodule
```

in the similar lines from the @oldfart answer use the FSM state names as sequence detected which will be helpful for reading code and understanding it easily, u can see the code below:

```
module moore_sequence_detector (
    input        clk,reset
   ,input [1:0]  ain
   ,output logic yout
);

logic nyout;
enum logic [2:0] {   START
                    ,SEEN_01,SEEN_0100
                    ,SEEN_11,SEEN_1100
                    ,SEEN_10,SEEN_1000
                    ,XXX = 'x
                 } state,next;

always_ff @(posedge clk or posedge reset)
    if(reset) state <= #1 START;
    else      state <= #1 next;

always_comb begin 
        next = 'x;
   casez(state)
    START    :case(ain)
               2'b01 : next = SEEN_01;
               2'b10 : next = SEEN_10;
               2'b11 : next = SEEN_11;
              endcase
    SEEN_01  :         next = (ain == 2'b00) ? SEEN_0100 : START;
    SEEN_10  :         next = (ain == 2'b00) ? SEEN_1000 : START;
    SEEN_11  :         next = (ain == 2'b00) ? SEEN_1100 : START;
    SEEN_0100:         next = START;
    SEEN_1100:         next = START;
    SEEN_1000:         next = START;
   endcase
end

always_ff @(posedge clk or posedge reset)
    if(reset) yout <= #1 1'b0;
    else      yout <= #1 nyout;

always_comb begin
        nyout = yout;
  casez(state)
   SEEN_0100 : nyout =  1'b0;
   SEEN_1000 : nyout =  1'b1;
   SEEN_1100 : nyout = ~yout;
  endcase
end

endmodule
```